# matplotlib plotting multiple lines in 3D

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, mplot3d

I am trying to plot multiple lines in a 3D plot using matplotlib. I have 6 datasets with x and y values. What I've tried so far was, to give each point in the data sets a z-value. So all points in data set 1 have z=1 all points of data set 2 have z=2 and so on.
Then I exported them into three files. "X.txt" containing all x-values, "Y.txt" containing all y-values, same for "Z.txt".

Here's the code so far:

```
        #!/usr/bin/python
        from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        import numpy as np
        import pylab

        xdata = '/X.txt'
        ydata = '/Y.txt'
        zdata = '/Z.txt'

        X = np.loadtxt(xdata)
        Y = np.loadtxt(ydata)
        Z = np.loadtxt(zdata)

        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
        ax.plot_wireframe(X,Y,Z)
        plt.show()
```

What I get looks pretty close to what I need. But when using wireframe, the first point and the last point of each dataset are connected. How can I change the colour of the line for each data set and how can I remove the connecting lines between the datasets?

Is there a better plotting style then wireframe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Load the data sets individually, and then plot each one individually.

I don't know what formats you have, but you want something like this

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})

datasets = [{"x":[1,2,3], "y":[1,4,9], "z":[0,0,0], "colour": "red"} for _ in range(6)]

for dataset in datasets:
    ax.plot(dataset["x"], dataset["y"], dataset["z"], color=dataset["colour"])

plt.show()
```

Each time you call `plot` (or `plot_wireframe` but i don't know what you need that) on an `axes` object, it will add the data as a new series. If you leave out the `color` argument `matplotlib` will choose them for you, but it's not too smart and after you add too many series' it will loop around and start using the same colours again.

n.b. i haven't tested this - can't remember if `color` is the correct argument. Pretty sure it is though.

Comment: Thank you a lot!! That helped me. Why I was using wireframe...thought it was the only way of plotting multiple lines in 3D. How stupid.... :)